# I'm getting the below error although I have made other form exactly like these but didnt get any error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMetroTextbox' to data type int.

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-1FDJLDP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=final;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand
("  update HOUSEHOLD 
set
 name= '" + NameTextbox.Text + "',
 weight='" + ColorTextbox.Text + "',
 brand='" + BrandNameTextbox.Text + "',
packsize='" + SizeTextbox.Text + "',
HOID='" + ItemNUmberTextbox.Text + "',
price='" + PriceTextbox.Text + "',
stock='" + StockTextbox.Text +"'
where HOID= '" + ItemNUmberTextbox + "';", con);
int o = com4.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(o + "Records has been updated:");
con.Close();
```

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD_(
HOID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
WEIGHT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
BRAND VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PACKSIZE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRICE INT NOT NULL,
STOCK INT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Oh my, this is ripe for SQL injection abuse. Are you really going to blindly append user input into an executable command?

Comment: Our good friend bobby tables loves this style of coding. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Anyway my guess might be with the upper-case U in `ItemNUmberTextbox`?

Comment: You forgot the `.Text` after `ItemNUmberTextbox`. The line should be `where HOID= '" + ItemNUmberTextbox.Text + "';", con);`. However, you should really use command parameters.

Comment: Agree with Aaron.  I think that you will solve your problem by validating the input then parameterizing your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

```
where HOID= '" + ItemNUmberTextbox + "';", con);
```

instead of

```
where HOID= '" + ItemNUmberTextbox.Text + "';", con);
```

forgetting the `.Text` part. This produces the exception.

---

Your method has other problems and should look something like this:

```
const string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-1FDJLDP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=final;Integrated Security=True";
const string updateSql = @"UPDATE household
    SET
      name = @name, weight = @weight, 
      brand = @brand, packsize = @packsize,
      price = @price, stock = @stock
    WHERE hoid = @hoid";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    var com4 = new SqlCommand(updateSql);
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NameTextbox.Text);
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", ColorTextbox.Text); // Why ColorTextbox for weight?
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", BrandNameTextbox.Text);
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@packsize", SizeTextbox.Text);
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(PriceTextbox.Text));
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", Convert.ToInt32(StockTextbox.Text));
    com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoid", Convert.ToInt32(ItemNUmberTextbox.Text));

    con.Open();
    int o = com4.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show($"{o} Record{(o == 1 ? " has" : "s have")} been updated.");
}
```

Enclose your connection object in a using-statement. This ensures that the connection will be closed and disposed.

Use command parameters. This takes care of texts containing apostrophes (') and prevents [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This also speeds up the query if it is called several times, since the query text now always looks the same and the SQL-Server can reuse the previous execution plan. And you must agree that the SQL text is more readable now.

Do not set `hoid` again. It has already the right value because of the where clause.

Also, the numbers (and all other paramameters of non-text type) should be converted to a type corresponding to the column definition in the table schema. I have not included error checking here, for the sake of simplicity. You should probably check whether the user input can really be convert to integers for the price, the stock and `hoid` before calling this method.

Comment: Thanks for guidance though the only thing I was missing was .Text and it worked!